# Word VBA code to cut numbers from one column and paste them in another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for some code that can search cell by cell in the 2nd column of a table for numbers and decimal points, cut them and paste them in the cell to the left whilst leaving the text behind.

For example:

- - 1(tab space)Test
- - 1.1(tab space)Test
- - 1.1.1(tab space)Test
- - 1.1.1.1(tab space)Test

Where the bullet points represent separate cells in different columns.

In all instances the numbers are separated from the text by a tab space "Chr9" (as indicated in the example)

Any help or useful snippets of code would much appreciated!

EDIT: I have some code that scans each cell in a column but I dont know the code to tell it to only cut numbers and decimal points up to the first tab space.

Comment: are there list paragraphs or the numbers are just manually typed?

Comment: they have been changed from autonumbering to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Split` function delivers what you are after. Sample code:

```
Dim inputString As String
Dim splitArray() As String
Dim result As String

inputString = "1 Test"
splitArray = Split(inputString, " ")

If(UBound(splitArray) >= 1) Then 'Making sure that it found something before using it
    result = splitArray(1) 'Text
End If

inputString = "1.1 Test"
splitArray = Split(inputString, " ")

If(UBound(splitArray) >= 1) Then
    result = splitArray(1) 'Text
End If
'etc.
```

UPDATE

Code delivering the functionality you want:

```
  Dim splitArray() As String
  Dim curTable As Table
  Set curTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For Row = 1 To curTable.Rows.Count
     With curTable
        splitArray = Split(.Cell(Row, 2).Range.Text, " ")

        If (UBound(splitArray) >= 1) Then 
           .Cell(Row, 2).Range.Text = splitArray(1)
           .Cell(Row, 1).Range.Text = splitArray(0)
        End If
     End With
  Next Row
```

Comment: Can you help me to understand that better please? I have a friend who is also trying to help, we have got to the stage where the code recognises the number of characters before the "tab space" but I dont know how to manipulate Range to select, cut and paste those characters

Comment: @AneeshS sure. The Split function divides the input string on account of certain character (in this case, " "). It returns an array containing all the elements starting from zero. That is, if you have a string "anything anything2"; the returned array will have 2 elements: first element (index 0) "anything"; second element (index 1) "anything2". If you case, what you are looking for is always present in the second position.

Comment: Can the code be applied in any scenario and I would like to paste the characters returned in the second position in the same row but one cell to its left...what do I add to the code?

Comment: @AneeshS you can replace inputString and result with what you want. For example, if the current cell is row 1 and column 1, you would have: splitArray = Split(Table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, " ") and Table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = splitArray(1)

Comment: Ok I will give it a go and let you know how I get on

Comment: @AneeshS OK. I look forward to your impressions. BTW, better make sure that the splitArray has the right size (= found something) before using it. Will update my code right now with a "safer version"

Comment: EDIT: yes it was on another document...just found it again

Comment: @AneeshS I thought that you have a code already in place. Don't you know how to loop through cells?

Comment: @AneeshS have you declared splitArray? (as shown in my example: Dim splitArray() As String)

Comment: @AneeshS And where are you getting this error? The provided code works fine; you are doing something wrong; please, post the code you wrote.

Comment: @AneeshS I have seen your edit right now and I am a bit confused: both codes are unrelated (and the error is triggered in the one I didn't write). Please, explain the exact point where you get the input string (e.g., "1 Test" ) and I will adapt your code with mine.

Comment: @AneeshS PS: I hope that you know that this site is for developers and for asking specific problems (not for deliver working solutions; you should be the one adapting my answer to your code).

Comment: Each cell in the 2nd column of my table contains numbers (with decimal points) followed by a tab space, followed by text in one of the four layouts given in my original example at the top. The text must remain in the cell (row n,2) and the numbers should be cut and pasted into the 1st column (row n,1). I hope that clears it up

Comment: I am sure you can tell I am quite new to this and I am sorry if I have annoyed you or not followed the Q&A rules. I am very grateful for all the help and advice you have given me

Comment: @AneeshS I understand what you want, but I am not sure about how it relates with the two codes writen. I will update my answer with a code delivering what you are asking for.

Comment: @AneeshS this is not annoying me, just telling you how this works and that I shouldn't be doing this, neither you asking here if you don't enough experience on the specific matter.

Comment: @AneeshS there you have a code delivering what you want. Please, in the future use this site as intended (if you don't know too much, better learn and come here with specific problems, not evident and helpful to others, not just to you).